# Magento 2.4.1: We can't find products matching this selection indexer issue

Tags: magento2.4.1, indexer

This error message keeps displaying across the category pages of our Magento 2.4.1 site. Indexer status is below. Not sure what is the cause of this recurrent issue.

[image]

Comment: any errors on magento logs or elasticsearch logs?

Comment: Is your cron running ? And please don't use all capitalized title.